# Facebook v2.3 Search Friends

Tags: facebook, api

i use app with v2.3 api, and i wanna to search a friend by name.
Fql was deprecated and with graph i don't know how.

```
$params = array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => "SELECT uid,name,pic_square from user where uid IN(select uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() AND strpos(lower(name),'".$search."') order by name limit 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search) in v2.x:

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=yourfriendname&type=user
```

Another way is to use `/me/friends` and go throug the results to find the friend by name. Keep in mind that you can only get those friends who authorized your App too though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this method return just irelevant results, not my friend who searched in facebook bar, not enough closer.
Sorry for my eng.